# TCP IP Peer-Peer Connection Matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp

I'm running a program where I establish both a server and client connection on one machine to another machine using the Instrument control toolbox, so it ends up more or less acting like a peer-peer connection.

The code runs fine the first time its run on the 2 seperate machines but sometimes it won't run on the 2nd try or if I leave Matlab open and try and run it later it won't run. All I get is one program trying to find the server and the other program has opened a server connection but they never find each other.

Code for opening connection(Client code is very similar):

```
function connectionServer = openRecieve(client, port)
t = tcpip(client, port, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
set(t, 'InputBufferSize', 3000000); 
% Open connection to the client.
fopen(t);
fprintf('%s \n','Client Connected');
connectionServer = t;
set(connectionServer,'Timeout',.1);
end
```

Code for closing connection:

```
function closeConnection(connection)
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here

fclose(connection); 
delete(connection); 
clear connection;

end
```

I don't think it has anything to do with the Timeouts because they have no problem connecting and running the first time.

I also added:

```
clc
clear all
```

To the end and beginning of my program and it still fails to connect sometimes on the 2nd or 3rd run.

Any thoughts are appreciated

Comment: I wonder if variable scope is ok for the `closeConnection`. If you do fclose, delete and clear outside of function in the base environment, will the second connection work?

Comment: They seem to connect fine the first time I run the program and usually the second its just when I run repeated runs it will start crashing...... is there anyway to check if fclose actually closed the connection?

Comment: Try to check the `Status` property of tcpip object, for example `get(connectionServer,'Status')` or maybe just `connectionServer.Status`. According to documentation it should return `open` if connection is open and `closed` otherwise.

Comment: Well I was gonna test that and then my trial version ran out....... guess I'm not gonna ever fix this one.